# Import Error: No Module named 'BluePrints'

Tags: python, module, builder, importerror

I am in the process of learning Python for a summer class, and have encountered this error: In the following code you will see I have a package which I load into Director.py, which I am using as my main file. However, BluePrints.py is missing when it is clearly in the directory. I have also checked numerous times for typing errors, but that is not the issue. There is no documentation on this issue in the book I am learning from, none that I can see in the Python documentation online, and cannot find this specific problem on StackOverflow. Here is my code:

```
# Director.py
from Builder import HouseBuilders as hb, HouseBuilderInterface as hbi 

interface = hbi.HouseBuilderInterface()   # An interface to my concrete builders
first_house = hb.EarthHomeBuilder()   # Initialize a concrete builder

interface.build_room(first_house, 'kitchen')  # Build a room in the Earth House
```

Builder/HouseBuilderInterface.py

```
class HouseBuilderInterface():

    """ HouseBuilder utilizes Python's duck-typing to provide an interface to the concrete house builders"""
    def build_room(obj, room_type):     # Rooms are an attribute shared by all houses
        obj.build_room(room_type)
    
    def build_wall(obj, room1, room2):  # Walls are an attribute shared by all houses; Duplex's will have a unique Dividing Wall
        obj.build_wall(room1, room2)
        
    def build_window(obj, wall):        # Windows are an attribute shared by all houses
        obj.build_window(wall)
        
    def build_door(obj):                # Doors are an attribute shared by all houses; Colonial and Split-level houses can have basement doors
        obj.build_door()
        
    def build_stairs(obj):              # Stairs can only be built in Colonial and Split-level houses; Colonial stair cases are bigger
        obj.build_stairs()
        
    def build_extra(obj):               # Some houses have extra features: Earth-homes have plants on the roof, Single-story has a wrap-around-porch, etc.
        obj.build_extra()
```

Builder/HouseBuilders.py

```
import BluePrints

class EarthHomeBuilder():

    def __init__(self):     # Initialize a simple house
        self.room_no = 0
        self.window_no = 0
        self.door_no = 1
        self.wall_no = 4
        self.key = 0                # key attribute is a unique key for the dictionary
        self.house_features = {}
        
    def build_room(self, room_type):
        new_room = BluePrints.Room(room_type)
        self.room_no += 1
        self.house_features[key] = room_type + ''
        self.key += 1
```

Builder/BluePrints.py

```
class Room():
    """ Defines a room object with an attribute of room_type"""
    def __init__(self, room_type):
        self.room_type = room_type
        
class Wall():
    """ Defines a Wall object with attributes of window and door """
    def __init__(self):     # Initialize windows & doors to 0 
        self.windows = 0
        self.doors = 0
        
    def add_window(self):
        self.windows += 1
        
    def add_door(self):
        self.doors += 1
        
class Window():
    """ Defines a Window object with no attributes; Adds a window to specified Wall object"""
    def __init__(wall_location):
        wall_location.add_window()      # Use duck-typing to call Wall method add_window()
        
class Door():
    """ Defines a Door object with no attributes; Adds a door to specified Wall object """
    def __init__(wall_location):
        wall_location.add_door()        # Use duck-typing to call Wall method add_door()
        
class StairCase():
    """ Defines a StairCase object with an attribute of length """
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
        
class ExtraFeature():
    """ Defines an ExtraFeature object which is unique type of house feature specific to each house """
    def __init__(self, extra_feature):
        self.extra_feature = extra_feature
```

Note: This assignment is an implementation of the Builder software pattern. Also, I have only been testing the build_room method, as seen in the Director.py file. I am not concerned with any bugs unless they pertain to the issue importing BluePrints.py The exact error message is ImportError: no module named 'BluePrints'

## Edit:

I am using Python3.4

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` file in `Builder` directory?

Comment: @Alik I believe he does, otherwise the error should be `cannot import name 'HouseBuilders` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar after rereading question and seeing, that the problem is about `BluePrints.py` module I came to conclusion, that you are right.

Comment: Please post exact error with full traceback. Also it would be really nice if you show us how you execute `Directory.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that after you have imported `HouseBuilders` into your Director.py , the `sys.path` still remains at the directory of the `Director.py` , and hence there are no `BluePrints.py` directly in any directory specified by `sys.path`.

And it is `sys.path` that python looks up when trying to find a package or class to import. Also I am guessing you are using Python 3.x .

A fix would be to do what the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) says -

> 6.4.2. Intra-package References
>
> When packages are structured into subpackages (as with the sound package in the example), you can use absolute imports to refer to submodules of siblings packages. For example, if the module sound.filters.vocoder needs to use the echo module in the sound.effects package, it can use from sound.effects import echo.

So in `Builder/HouseBuilders.py` , change your import statement to -

```
from Builder import BluePrints
```

Comment: If `Builder` is a package, then `import BluePrints` should work just fine, without any need to modify `sys.path`. Related part of documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)

Comment: @Alik Did you try that out? It didn't work for me, Let me try to dig a little deeper

Comment: @Alik Seems like OP is using Python 3.x , it has changed a bit in Python 3.x . Thanks.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, sys.path finds the folder containing Director.py. This module imports all but BluePrints.py from the package Builder. HouseBuilders.py, now located in the same folder as Directory.py in terms of sys.path, tries to import BluePrints.py from the current folder. But BluePrints.py can't be imported without the "from Builder" command. Is this correct?

Comment: Well, second part you are correct, first part no,Housebuilders.py is not located in the same folder as Directory.py , python correctly knows where to look for it. But inside `HouseBuilders.py` when you do - `import BluePrints` , without giving any package name, python thinks you are trying to import the `BluePrints.py` from the same folder as `Director.py` , but python cannot find any such file, hence giving the error. Python thinks like that because you are running `Director.py` script.

Comment: Ok, I was coding with the understanding that if the two modules (BluePrints.py and HouseBuilders.py in this case) were in the same package that the sys.path would know to look there if one called the other. I understand how sys.path is searching now. Thank you.

Comment: They would have known, if it was Python 2.x , but it got changed in Python 3.x , because that was making cod more complicated (since from an inner submodule, to call some script in an outer module it was very complex).